# Detect tablet or desktop user

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, jsp

I plan to have a completely separate layout/design for a desktop Vs tablet user. My app is based on Java.
My questions are;
1. What is the best approach to detect whether the request is coming from desktop or tablet (iPad/Xoom, etc)
2. Can this be handled at server-side and not through JS user-agent string?

A live example of redirect is if one tries to access Yahoo. i.e. if the request comes from a desktop browser, we’ll be redirected to www.yahoo.com , while if the request comes from a tablet device like iPad, we’ll be redirected to www.yahoo.com/tablet
I am planning something along the Yahoo example. Not sure how they have implemented it.

I know some of you might be thinking that I should just control 2 separate CSS like desktop.css and tablet.css and detect through CSS media query OR JS user-agent. But the point is the layout/design is so different between the 2 that I just cannot control only via CSS and that is the reason, I plan to have a separate tablet version of my web app and do the redirection.

Please let me know as much suggestions that you can.

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Comment: I don't get it: why not use 'user-agent' at server side?

Comment: user-agent detecting would make it easier for you. Other than that, you can detect the screen width resolution but probably not what you want.

Comment: I have read in many places that user-agent string is kind of inconsistent..So it should be avoided for browser detection..Also not sure how it works at server-side..

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to test for the browser type.  You never know what's coming next, after all.  Consider testing for capability.  The Modernizr library has a full feature detection suite that will tell you what the current browser can and can't support.  Use media-queries to detect screen size, and responsive design to deal with it.  And if the design is "so different," aren't you setting yourself up on a maintenance headache?

Comment: Yes exactly..it's going to be hard to maintain..but unfortunately, as a developer, i don't have a great say in the design..i'm looking for the best approach to support the 2 separate designs..and in fact, even though i say design, it's going to be not just UI work, but on the Java side as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for the user-agent string within your HTTP request. Based on that you will be able to identify the device -- provided that the user has not altered the user-agent string sent from the device browser.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to deal with pretty much the same issue, having to differantiate between Desktop or Not-Desktop. I went with a client-side detection using JavaScript. I'm using RequireJS in my solution, and here's my module:

```
define(function(){
    var isTouchDevice = function() {  return window.screenX === 0 && 'ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window; };
    var isDesktop = !isTouchDevice() ? true : false;
    return isDesktop;
});
```

I've added the variable isDesktop for readability.

Comment: My Asus Zenbook Infinity has a touch screen but is not a tablet... sadly there isn't really a good way to make this determination. (Heck, I have a Fujitsu laptop from about 2002 that also has a touch screen...)